# Optimizely experiment/variation id/name

Tags: ab-testing, optimizely

I am trying to figure out where i can find the **experiment_id**, e**xperiment_name**, **variation_id** and **variation_name** on optimizely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the UI you can click options -> Diagnostic Report.

The experiment_id is also available in the URL of the editor window (`?experiment_id=123456789`)

If you're in js code you can access them through the `optimizely.variationNamesMap[${experimentId}]`, `optimizely.activeExperiments[${experimentId}]`, and `optimizely.allExperiments[${experimentId}]`.

There is also a way to access them via the `optimizely.data` object.

```
lat name = window.optimizely.data.experiments[experimentId].name;
lat val = window.optimizely.variationNamesMap[experimentId];
```

Docs: https://help.optimizely.com/QA_Campaigns_and_Experiments/The_console,_data_object,_and_Optimizely_log